# TCP connection severing in Two arm load balanced environment using Kemp LoadMaster connecting to Centos servers

Tags: load-balancing, tcp, timeout

The configuration is one that I inherited but the connection from the LoadMaster to two appserver ends up occasionally getting severed.  This will happen to each server independently, and only seems to occur during low volume periods.

When recording TCP dumps I can see the handshake ACK sent from the appserver to the LoadMaster but it never reaches the destination.  When running traceroute using TCP during a time of failure it routes the first hop through the default gateway and ends up timing out, if the connection is working it just route directly to the LoadMaster.

The standard traceroute using ICMP never fails or times out, but does end up being routed through the default gateway when TCP is showing as timing out.  If I disable/enable anything on the LoadMaster, the connection gets restored and traceroute no longer routes through the default gateway but only for a brief time if the volume is light and goes back to failing.

I presume the issue must either reside on the network or the LoadMaster but don't know any next troubleshooting steps to pinpoint the issue (I've been a coder most of my life and only dabbled in Network stuff) and it seems to be over the head of the Network guys I work with.